# Using django-piston, how can I write out HTTP headers in the response?

Tags: django, django-piston

How can I include an HTTP header, such as Cache-Control or Last-Modified, in the response to a django-piston call?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it in your `urls.py` following the procedure in the [specifying per view cache in urlconf](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/cache/#specifying-per-view-cache-in-the-urlconf) guide in the Django documentation. In my case I had my Piston API in a separate module and prefer to use Varnish instead of the built-in Django caching framework so I used this approach in my `api/urls.py` (which my main `urls.py` includes) to set the cache control headers I wanted:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

cached_resource = cache_control(public=True, maxage=30, s_maxage=300)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^myresource/$', cached_resource(Resource(MyHandler))),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about django-piston, but in django you can just go:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
response = HttpResponse('My content')
response['MyHttpHeader'] = 'MyHeaderValue'
```

So, do that where you can get access to the response.  Middleware is often the perfect place to do this if you are using a 3rd party application.  Your middleware could look something like:

```
def process_response(self, request, response):
    response['MyHttpHeader'] = 'MyHeaderValue'
    return response
```